# Forge create custom markup with a hyperlink

Tags: autodesk-forge, markup, autodesk

I have followed the tutorial at https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/implementing-custom-markups to create a custom markup type. I am just wondering whether it is possible to create a custom markup that can contain a hyperlink to an external web url and when it is clicked, it opens in a new tab. It would effectively look like adding standard text, but with the text being clickable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another solution is create div with position absolute in Forge div, so that div can move around in. You can use click event to define uv coordinate for where you pin that div. With div you can put anything inside, include hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.
In the example blog, SVG is used for drawing, in SVG you can have links, instead of SVG you can add text and links.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will give it a go and see how I get on!

Comment: Is there an example anywhere which demonstrates this? The only examples I can find just use the path element.

Comment: We don't have an example, but it should be easy to test. Please add an SVG element with hyperlink(https://alligator.io/svg/hyperlinks-svg/) and let me know how it goes.